# get 32 bit number in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to get a 32 bit number in objective c when an byte array is passed to it, similarly as in java where,

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(truncation);   
return bb.getInt();
```

Where truncation is the byte array.
It returns 32 bit number.. Is this possible in objective c?

Comment: Ok I didn't think so but let me clarify: does this byte array come from network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number is encoded in little-endian within the buffer, then use:

```
int32_t getInt32LE(const uint8_t *buffer)
{
    int32_t value = 0;
    unsigned length = 4;
    while (length > 0)
    {
        value <<= 8;
        value |= buffer[--length];
    }
    return value;
}
```

If the number is encoded in big-endian within the buffer, then use:

```
int32_t getInt32BE(const uint8_t *buffer)
{
    int32_t value = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        value <<= 8;
        value |= *buffer++;
    }
    return value;
}
```

**UPDATE** If you are using data created on the same host then endianness is not an issue, in which case you can use a `union` as a *bridge* between the buffer and integers, which avoids some unpleasant casting:

```
union
{
    uint8_t b[sizeof(int32_t)];
    int32_t i;
} u;

memcpy(u.b, buffer, sizeof(u.b));
// value is u.i
```

Comment: thanks..can u pls help me .. i have an array of bytes for eg <__NSArrayI 0x71d2c70>(-57,-80,-107,-71,-47,90,-45,-30,57,-34,) then how should i copy it into the const uint8_t *buffer..to use in the function above...

Comment: @SaurabhJadhav Ask a new SO question.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri See my comment to your answer.

Comment: IMHO also if he has reversed bytes, do the same and use ntohl().

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the endianness:

```
uint32_t n = b0 << 24 | b1 << 16 | b2 << 8 | b3;
```

or

```
uint32_t n = b3 << 24 | b2 << 16 | b1 << 8 | b0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you just want to read 4 bytes and assign that value to an integer. This case:

```
int32_t number;
memcpy(&number, truncation, sizeof(uint32_t));
```

**About endianess**

From your question (for me) was clear that the bytes were already ordered correctly. However if you have to re-order these bytes, use `ntohl()` after `memcpy()` :

```
number=ntohl(number);
```

Comment: That will work only if the integers in the buffer are encoded in the same endianness as the host.  This is not the case for most network protocols (which generally use big endian) where most CPUs are generally little-endian these days.

Comment: Ok, you would be right but he doesn't talk about any host. We don't know from where does his data come.

Comment: Exactly; it was unspecified.

Comment: But that's just not part of the question, I mean, if one says to have an array of bytes, then comes obvious that this array hasn't reversed bytes.

Comment: He mentioned that he has the bytes in a comment to my answer, not in the original question, and who's to say where  *those* bytes came from (it could have been from a network packet from a host running big-endian or adhering to the standard of using big-endian to encode integers).

Comment: IMHO his question implies that the bytes are already ordered correctly, however I edited the answer just to be sure.